# Can I install pip in my local directory rather than ~/local?

Tags: python, bash, unix, pip, putty

I am trying to install pip via SSH. I have been trying to install it for my local directory using the following command

```
python get-pip --my.directory
```

I get the following result:

```
Checking for setuptools...
Downloading http://pypi.python.org/packages/2.4/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg

Installing pip...
error: None
```

Now when I check the installation, by typing
        pip
I get the following result:

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

So I am wondering if I can install pip in my local directory or not? If I can, is there any alternate way to do that?

P.S, I am new to Linux/Unix, if anyone can share some helpful tutorial, it would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm on the fence as to whether this is on-topic. Although [questions about tools used primarily for programming are on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), this sounds more like an OS issue to me, which would belong at [Super User](http://superuser.com). Is there some reason you believe that the issue is specific to pip?

Comment: I think if installation did not raise any error, than it must work. Therefore there is a possibility that pip has some problem.

Comment: Fair enough. I encountered this post in a review queue. It had received an off-topic close vote, but I wasn't sure whether or not it's on-topic. I'd say it depends on the resolution. It's not a coding question, but if it's specific to the configuration of a package installer for a programming language then I'd say it's on-topic. If it turns out to be an OS issue, then I'd vote to close or migrate to Super User.

Answer (score 0):

The directory you install pip into needs to be on your path in order to call the `pip` command. You can add it by using the export command:

```
export PATH=<absolute path to pip's directory>;$PATH
```

To make this permanent just add it your shell's rc file, typically `<home>/.bashrc`.